# Errors with passing parameters among screens Java FXML

Tags: java, java-8, javafx-2, fxml

Now i have some problems when i try passing parameter among screens

This is my LogIn controller:

```
   @FXML
public void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    String text = textFieldLogIn.getText();
    Stage stage = new Stage();

    if(text.length() != 0){

        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Menu.fxml"));
        MenuController controller = fxmlLoader.<MenuController>getController();
        Parent root = (Parent)fxmlLoader.load(); 

        stage = (Stage) btnLogIn.getScene().getWindow();

        detail.setName("Tu");
            controller.setDetail(detail);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);


        stage.show();
    }
    else{
        notiLogIn.setText("Please enter your name");
        notiLogIn.setTextFill(Color.RED);
    }
```

This is my class CustomerDetails:

```
public class CustomerDetails {
String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAttendance() {
    return attendance;
}

public void setAttendance(int attendance) {
    this.attendance = attendance;
}

public double getTotalBill() {
    return totalBill;
}

public void setTotalBill(double totalBill) {
    this.totalBill = totalBill;
}
int attendance;
double totalBill;
```

This is my MenuController:

```
public class MenuController implements Initializable {
  CustomerDetails detail = new CustomerDetails();

public CustomerDetails getDetail() {
    return detail;
}

public void setDetail(CustomerDetails detail) {
    this.detail = detail;
}
@FXML
private AnchorPane menuPane;
@FXML
private SplitPane menuSplitPane;
@FXML
private AnchorPane menuPane1;
@FXML
private VBox menuVBox;
@FXML
private Button btnFood;
@FXML
private Button btnDrink;
@FXML
private Button btnOther;
@FXML
private Button btnBill;
@FXML
private Label menuWelcome;
@FXML
private AnchorPane displayMenu;
```

So now i got problem that when i'm using the getController() with the controller.setDetail(detail) i got an error about java.lang.NullPointerException and i cannot pass the value to Screen 2: Menu. So what should i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not about parameter passing.
You got a `NullPointerException` because `controller` is null, not because `details` is null.

Here you get the controller with `getController` before you call `load`.

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Menu.fxml"));
MenuController controller = fxmlLoader.<MenuController>getController();
Parent root = (Parent)fxmlLoader.load();
```

The [load](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load--) method loads the object hierarchy from an FXML document and also this method creates an controller object for you which can be retrieved by `getController()`.

**Solution:** get the controller after you have loaded the FXML file:

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Menu.fxml"));
Parent root = (Parent)fxmlLoader.load();
MenuController controller = fxmlLoader.<MenuController>getController();
```